# Why are the worlds of Might & Magic referred to as "nacelles"?

Tags: names, might-and-magic

Some worlds in the original Might&Magic universe are named "nacelle":

- (VARN) Vehicular Astropod Research Nacelle
- (CRON) Central Research Observation Nacelle
- (XEEN) Xylonite Experimental Environment Nacelle

However, none of the dictionary meanings of the world 'nacelle' mean 'world' or 'planet'. I thought the word might also mean 'spaceship' somehow as in "a world floating through space" but none of the dictionary meanings I could find mean spaceship either.

What does the word "nacelle" mean in this context?

Comment: Nacelle is Star Trek-ese for the bit that sticks out of the ship

Comment: It's a 'streamlined enclosure' [though why you'd need streamlining in space…]

Comment: @Valorum the casing holding an aircraft engine is a nacelle, so it’s fairly natural for the structure that holds the warp coils to have the same name.

Answer (score 4):

A nacelle in *Might and Magic*, is a large slab like structure created by the ancients.

The English word [Nacelle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nacelle#:%7E:text=Kids%20Definition-,nacelle,or%20sometimes%20for%20the%20crew) comes from French and means small boat. So I would presume that they are meant to be "boats", traveling through space, supporting life.

> The nacelle is a colossal structure created by the Ancients through elemental manipulation to serve in their great experiments. Entire worlds were placed on nacelles, and then populated and then sent out through the void to fulfill their purpose. Smaller VARNs (Vehicular Astropod Research Nacelle) can be placed inside CRONs (Central Research Observational Nacelle).

[Nacelle in Might and Magic](https://mightandmagic.fandom.com/wiki/Nacelle)